# How to add lists together F#

Tags: visual-studio, f#

Below is part of my code, I have many rooms called r# and have put them in lists of their respective rows, however at the end I am trying to put all these lists together to form a large list including all rooms.
I am not trying to make a list of the separate lists but a list of all the rooms! Line 9 seems to be the problem, seems I am using the cons operator wrong

```
let r58 = {id=58;item=pot2;n=0;e=0;s=51;w=0;complete=false}
let r59 = {id=59;item=m13;n=60;e=0;s=55;w=0;complete=false}
let row11 = [r58;r59]

let r60 = {id=60;item=m8;n=61;e=0;s=59;w=0;complete=false}
let r61 = {id=61;item=m9;n=0;e=0;s=60;w=0;complete=false}
let row12 = [r60;r61]

let roomlist = row1::row2::row3::row4::row5::row6::row7::row8::row9::row10::row11::row12

roomlist
```

Comment: You can append lists using `@`: `row11 @ row12 @ ...`.

Comment: If you have multiple lists, `List.concat` is better than using `@`. The `@` operator works on two lists at a time, so it will go through the first list multiple times. `a @ b @ c @ d` first adds `a` and `b` together, then it takes the `ab` list and adds `c` to it, then it takes the `abc` list and adds `d` to it. Since F# lists are a linked-list structure that must be iterated from the head in order to reach the tail, that means that `a` gets iterated four times. With `List.concat`, on the other hand, `a` would only be iterated once. So `List.concat` is more efficient for multiple lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To concatenate multiple lists, use `List.concat`:

```
List.concat [row1; row2; row3; ... row12]
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, would you mind accepting it? You can do this by clicking a gray checkmark image to the left of the question.